# adding call to function before assigning values

Tags: sql, coldfusion, ide, grep, text-editor

A sanitize function was added to prevent SQL injection by stripping certain characters. It sure is hard to manually go through all the files and find where the function should be added. Is there a way to automate this process or use find/replace? What I'm currently doing is looking for `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements and inside them I look for `#...#` and replace it with `#sanitize(...)#` but it may be more complicated if there are multiple columns being updated in a table.

EDIT: can grep be used? If you don't know the answer please consider voting this question up.

Comment: Read up on triggers, particularly update and insert before triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql injection can take place in a SELECT call as well as any other sql call.  Not just UPDATE and INSERT.

Comment: also you don't really have to sanitize every db call.  just on user input.  not sure if that helps any...

Comment: does the code <CFQUERY name="checkSuppliers" datasource="#REQUEST.dsn#"> need sanitization?

Comment: changing the datasource won't impact your database... i'm not too familiar with CF but is #REQUEST.dsn# coming from the user? That seems odd that they'd dictate the server connection.

Answer (score 1):

Also look into cfqueryparam. Not only will this help prevent SQL injection, it also offers a slight performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

You can globally do this in your Application.cfm or Application.cfc file.

```
<cfloop collection="#form#" item="fItem">
   <cfset form[fItem] = SanitizeFunction(form[fItem])/>
</cfloop>
```

Add a loop for URL, CGI and Cookie and you have effectively examined each of the user provided variables. This is the concept behind a "Web Application Firewall" - something that examines every user input and scrubs it or validates it to make sure it is what it claims to be.

Check out super guru Pete Freitag's product [Foundeo](http://foundeo.com/) for an example. He has a great many other resources. WAFs usually look for other possible vulnerabilities, not just SQLi - so they can be worth your time.

As stated by Scott - you really should examine each query and add cfqueryparam for defense in depth.